# Electron ERROR Error: Cannot find module 'mysql' Require stack:

Tags: node.js, electron, package.json, electron-builder, mysqljs

My Electron app uses a nodejs dependency (in my case it's mysqljs) and it works fine when running on development mode.

However when I build it and launch as a native desktop app, it fails with:

> Electron ERROR Error: Cannot find module 'mysql' Require stack: ...

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I accidentally placed `mysql` between the `devDependencies` of my `package.json` file.

It should instead be placed within the `dependencies` since it is supposed to be shipped with the app.